# Android cannot resolve constructor intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, constructor, compiler-errors

Here is a section of my code. I am trying to make a navigation menu in which when you click on the first list item it launches the activity `MrsClubb`. However when I put this into my code it comes up with the error:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,java.lang.Class<com....etc>)'
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

The double ** shows where in the code the error is.

Here is the section of the code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerListItems));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent**(this, MrsClubb.class);**
                    startActivity(i);
            }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
    });
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v){
            super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Use `view.getContext()` instead of `this` as first parameter to Intent constructor

Comment: @Zygotelnit yeah I have, unfortunately I have to wait 90 minutes to post but when I do post it I'll post a link here for you to see.

Comment: @JonathanChappell: awaiting your question :)

Comment: @Zygotelnit here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352104/app-stops-working-when-i-call-a-second-activity-from-list-view-click

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**The Problem:**

You cannot use `this` to refer to the `Activity` inside an inner class, as `this` becomes a reference to the inner class. The meaning of the `constructor not resolved` message is that the compiler interprets it as

```
Intent(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener, Class class)
```

which it does not recognize, instead of

```
Intent(Context context, Class class)
```

which is correct and what the compiler expects.

**The Solution:**

Replace

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MrsClubb.class);
```

with

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MrsClubb.class);
```

where `MyActivity` is the name of the `Activity` class in which this code belongs.

Comment: Thank you! the error is resolved however whenever I run my app and click on position 0 the app stops running.