# App stops working when I call a second activity from nav drawer click

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

When I click on the first position of my list view I want it to take me to another activity, and when I click on the second position I want it to take me to a different activity..etc. I have tried to write code that when I click on the first item of my list view it takes me to the activity "MrsClubb" but whenever I click on the item it comes up with the message "unfortunately "app name" has stopped working" and then the app closes.

Any ideas?

Here is the code for various bits of my app:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
String[] mDrawerListItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerListItems));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MrsClubb.class);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
    });
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View v){
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View v){
            super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home: {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            return true;
        }
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jonatboard.jonat.htssoundboard" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

The activity I want the item to take me to when it is click is currently empty and only has this code in it:

```
public class MrsClubb {
}
```

If you need to see any more code to help you then please let me know.

Comment: please paste your logcat

Comment: `MrsClubb` has to extend `Activity` and must be declared in the manifest

Comment: @JonathanChappell: have you seen my answer ?

Comment: @Zygotelnit here is a new post regarding a newer situation that has the same problem. Your help is greatly appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355881/app-stops-working-when-i-call-a-second-activity-with-nav-drawer-from-nav-drawer

Comment: @Zygotelnit hey, that problem has already been solved. Do you think you can check out this problem that I've been facing for a long time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365566/app-crashes-when-i-open-another-activity-containing-soundpool thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `MrsClubb` class as

```
public class MrsClubb extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        setContentView(R.id.mrsClubbLayout);
        ....
        ....

    }

}
```

and override the `onCreate()` method of the `Activity` class (at the very least). Also add the declaration in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MrsClubb"
    android:label="@string/mrs_clubb_activity_title" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
public class MrsClubb extends Activity{}
```

and add to your manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MrsClubb"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mrs_clubb" />
```